# Hibernate JPQL performance difference

Tags: hibernate

I have these entities:

Product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Double price;
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private Set<ProductImages> images = new HashSet<>();
...
```

Product Images:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_images")
public class ProductImages implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "is_default")
    private Boolean isDefault;

    @Column(name = "url")
    private String url;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("images")
    private Product product;

getter & setters
```

I am wondering is there any performance difference between these two:

1) Eager fetch images

2 Lazy fetch and

```
Page<ProductDetailsDTO> newArrival = productRepository.getAllProductDtoByCategory(id, pageable);
        newArrival.forEach(dto -> {
        dto.setImages(productImagesRepository.getAllImagesByProductId(dto.getId()));
        });
```

This is only one. I have a more than **5 Set** in Product entity and every time I have to set some values in it.

Answer (score 0):

EAGER fetching is bad for performance so it’s better to use the FetchType.LAZY fetching strategy for all association types.

Fetching using JPQL:

```
Product product = entityManager.createQuery(
"select p " +
        "from Product p " +
        "where p.id = :productId", Product.class)
.setParameter("productId", productId)
.getSingleResult();
```

Generates the following SQL SELECT statements:

```
Query:{[
select
    product0_.id as id1_18_, 
    product0_.code as code2_18_, 
    product0_.company_id as company_6_18_, 
    product0_.importer_id as importer7_18_, 
    product0_.name as name3_18_, 
    product0_.quantity as quantity4_18_, 
    product0_.version as version5_18_ 
from Product product0_ 
where product0_.id=?][1]} 

Query:{[
select
    company0_.id as id1_6_0_, 
    company0_.name as name2_6_0_ 
from Company company0_ 
where company0_.id=?][1]}
```

Both JPQL and Criteria queries default to select fetching, therefore issuing a secondary select for each individual EAGER association. The larger the associations’ number, the more additional individual SELECTS, the more it will affect our application performance.

Reference: [EAGER fetching is a code smell when using JPA and Hibernate by VLAD MIHALCEA](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/)